# Delete parentId from EntitySubscription

Tags: visualforce, soql, chatter

I want to unfollow a user I am following on Chatter.
So I have passed the parentId of the user into the 'currentId' variable below. Now I want to remove it from the EntitySubscription. I'm a little rusty when it come to SQL.

This isnt working, could someone point me in the right direction?

```
public PageReference myMethod(){
    System.debug(' passed id: ' + currentParentId);
    return null;

    DELETE FROM EntitySubscription 
    WHERE parentId = currentId; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also would want to ensure that you are only deleting entitysubscriptions where the current user is the subscriber. Assuming that the current user is the one that wants to be unsubscribed, otherwise you will also have to pass that variable.

```
public PageReference myMethod()
{
    System.debug(' passed id: ' + currentParentId);

    Try
    {
        EntitySubscription subscription = [ SELECT ID FROM EntitySubscription 
                                            WHERE ParentId = : currentParentId 
                                            AND SubscriberId = : userinfo.getuserid() Limit 1];
        Delete subscription;
    }
        catch(Exception ex)
    {
        system.debug('Oops there was a boo boo::' + ex);
    }

return null;
}
```

Something like this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, how could I incorporate this into the method above?

Comment: No Worries, just Copy & Paste. also move your return null statement to after the try catch.

Comment: Edited the original comment, that should work. Maybe think about adding a nicely formatted page message in the catch if you are using <apex:pagemessages>

Comment: Excellent! It works perfectly!! Cheers again Mitch!